# How do I get function called on page load to work with button

Tags: javascript, html

```
let n = document.getElementById('input').value;
const answer = document.getElementById('answer');
const button = document.getElementById('start');
button.addEventListener('click', isPrime(n));

function isPrime(n) {
  if (n === 1) {
    answer.innerHTML = '1 is neither a prime nor a composit number. It is a unit.';
  } else if (n < 0) {
    answer.innerHTML = 'It must be a positiv number.'
  }
  for (const d = 2; d <= n; d++) {
    if (n % d == 0){
        answer.innerHTML = 'It is not a Prime Number';
        break;
    } else {
        answer.innerHTML = 'It is a Prime Number';
    }
  }
}
```

it is a simple web page with an input, button and a paragraph.
When the user inputs a number and presses the button, the paragraph should change wether it is a prime or not. But it only works by refreshing the site and not by button press...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the value of the input immediately with `let n = document.getElementById('input').value;` then you are calling the `isPrime` function immediately as well.

You could do something like this:

```
const answer = document.getElementById('answer');
const button = document.getElementById('start');
button.addEventListener('click', isPrime); // dont call the function, just pass it.

function isPrime() {
  let n = document.getElementById('input').value; // get the value when function runs.
  if (n === 1) {
    answer.innerHTML = '1 is neither a prime nor a composit number. It is a unit.';
  } else if (n < 0) {
    answer.innerHTML = 'It must be a positiv number.'
  }
  for (const d = 2; d <= n; d++){
    if (n % d == 0){
      answer.innerHTML = 'It is not a Prime Number';
      break;
    } else {
      answer.innerHTML = 'It is a Prime Number';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in your `button.addEventListener('click', isPrime(n));` call you are calling the `isPrime` function instead of passing the function to it. It should work if you change the addEventListener call to this:

```
button.addEventListener('click', isPrime);
```

You will probably have to get the number from the input in the `isPrime` function however instead of passing the number in.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const button = document.getElementById('start');
button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    let n = document.getElementById('input').value;
const answer = document.getElementById('answer');
    isPrime(n);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reassign a value to the `const` variable, here is the working example.

**HTML**

```
<input id="input"/>
<p id="answer"></p>
<button id="start">Start</button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var answer = document.getElementById('answer');
const button = document.getElementById('start');
button.addEventListener('click', function(){
  let n = document.getElementById('input').value;
  isPrime(n)
});

function isPrime(n) {
  console.log(n)
if (n === 1) {
    answer.innerHTML = '1 is neither a prime nor a composit number. It is a unit.';
} else if (n < 0) {
    answer.innerHTML = 'It must be a positiv number.'
}
for (let d = 2; d <= n; d++){
    if (n % d == 0){
        answer.innerHTML = 'It is not a Prime Number';
        break;
    } else {
        answer.innerHTML = 'It is a Prime Number';
    }
}
}
```

**Codepen** - https://codepen.io/askannan/pen/XWjrVYb